# How to access aggregated messages after Loop in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I get aggregated message after Camel's 2.16.1 [Loop](http://camel.apache.org/loop.html)? The only output I'm getting is the last message that was handled in the loop.

My loop iterates three times and there's aggregator that combines bodies in single String. The loop looks like this:

```java
from("timer:begin?repeatCount=1&delay=1")
.routeId("timer")
.to("direct:loop")
.log("Body after Loop Route: ${body}");

from("direct:loop")
.routeId("loop")
.loop(3)
    .setBody().simple("Hello ${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}")
    .log("Body in Loop: ${body}")
    .aggregate(new AggregationStrategy() {

        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            if (oldExchange == null) {
                return newExchange;
            }
            else {
                String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                String newBody = oldBody + ", " + newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                newExchange.getIn().setBody(newBody);
                return newExchange;
            }
        }
    }).constant(true).completionSize(3)
    .log("Body after Aggregate: ${body}")
.end();
```

The problem is that in the *timer*-route I am unable to access the aggregated message. Instead the *timer*-route in the example outputs **Hello 2** like this:

```
Body in Loop: Hello 0
Body in Loop: Hello 1
Body in Loop: Hello 2
Body after Aggregate: Hello 0, Hello 1, Hello 2
Body after Loop Route: Hello 2
```

Comment: What prevents you from using the aggregated message in the route "loop"?

Comment: Well that's the problem: how do I access it? Edit: misread your comment. It's not applicable for me to use it in the loop-route.

Comment: the pipeline for the aggregated result is executed asynchronously and can't update the exchange used in the loop - i don't think it's possible to use an aggregate processor to do what you wants, but you can just use a simple processor. by default, the exchange is not copyied

Comment: You can send aggregated message to another route (after `.log("Body after Aggregate: ${body}")`), using `direct`, `seda`, `activemq`, `vm` components. This may be another route, not the "timer" route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figure figure out how to do this with Loop. It says however in Camel web site that [Loop](http://camel.apache.org/loop.html) is

> Useful mostly during testing.

so I went the other way.

So, to iterate over some values like in a loop and get the aggregated result I modified the route to use [Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) and [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) like this

```
from("timer:begin?repeatCount=1&delay=1")
.routeId("timer")
.to("direct:splitter-loop")
.log("Body after Loop Route: ${body}");

from("direct:splitter-loop")
.routeId("splitter-loop")
.process(exchange -> {
    // Add items that you want to iterate over to body or header
    // and later use splitter over those items.
    List<String> loopIndex = new ArrayList<String>();
    loopIndex.add("1");
    loopIndex.add("2");
    loopIndex.add("3");
    exchange.getOut().setBody(loopIndex);
})
.split(body(), new StringAggregator())
    .setBody().simple("Hello ${body}")
    .log("Body in Loop: ${body}")
.end()
.log("Body after Aggregate: ${body}");
```

Where the `StringAggregator` is like before like this:

```
public class StringAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            return newExchange;
        }
        else {
            String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            String newBody = oldBody + ", " + newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(newBody);
            return newExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

This route now gives me the desired aggregated result like this

```
Body in Loop: Hello 1
Body in Loop: Hello 2
Body in Loop: Hello 3
Body after Aggregate: Hello 1, Hello 2, Hello 3
Body after Loop Route: Hello 1, Hello 2, Hello 3
```